# Getting an output from a subprocess from a separate window python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program which lets the user select a variety of options which will contribute to a command that will run in a separate window in python. After this sub-process finishes, I would like it to exit and return whatever the output is for that particular command. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
if(fileName == "" or className == ""):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "Please select a test class/test!")
else:
    command = "ctetest"
    if(verbose.get()):
        command += " -v"
    if(xml.get()):
        command += " -x"
    if(version.get()):
        command += " -V"
    if(output.get()):
        command += " -o"
    command += " RegressionTest/"
    command += folderName + " " + fileName + "." + className + "." + methodName
    processOutput = subprocess.Popen('start '+command, shell = True)
    processOutput.wait()
    processOutput.terminate()
```

The problem is that when the subprocess finishes, it just hangs there and I have to close it manually. Once I close it manually, it does not seem to generate any of the output produced by the subprocess. I have tried using

```
subprocess.check_output('start '+command, shell = True)
```

as well as

```
subprocess.popen('start '+command+' & exit', shell=True)
```

But same issue arises. The only work around I can think of is using threads but then how could I check if the subprocess is actually finish before I terminate it? Are there any other ways that I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(...)` is what you need here. Note that `subprocess` sometimes has tricky ways of requiring arguments to programs, you need to pass your arguments in a list, like so: `["program_name", "arg1", "arg2"]`

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` needs you to pass the arguments differently than what you're doing, you need to create a list that consists of the program to be run and it's arguments. For example `["ls", "-l", "/home"]`.

So, your code would need to be this:

```
if(fileName == "" or className == ""):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "Please select a test class/test!")
else:
    command = ["start ctetest"]
    if(verbose.get()):
        command.append("-v")
    if(xml.get()):
        command.append("-x")
    if(version.get()):
        command.append("-V")
    if(output.get()):
        command.append("-o")
    commandpath = "RegressionTest/" + folderName + " " + fileName + "." + className + "." + methodName
    command.append(commandpath)
    processOutput = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

This creates the list of command and arguments with `list.append()`. It will automatically wait for the subprocess to finish and provide the entire output in the `processOutput` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However it still seems to hang right after the subprocess finishes. If I try to add 
`command.append("exit")`
it just complains because it thinks that "exit" is part of the command that I was building. But in reality I want to run "exit" right after my custom command so that it can exit

Comment: @Ted there's no need to exit the shell after running the command. How do you know if your subprocess has finished or if it is just taking a long time? Execution is blocking, so it will hang until it is done.

Comment: I can see that once the process finishes it returns the command back to me, so I can type in other commands such as "dir". So my custom command is definitely finished executing by then. Does the fact that I am running this in a separate window have anything to do with this? I noticed that you put in `command = ["start ctetest"]`, so "start" is actually used to start a new window and not part of my custom command that I am building. I made the appropriate changes doing `command = ["start","ctetest"]`

Comment: So my logic is that "start" creates a subprocess in a new window and my command was called inside this new window, but once it is finished, it just sits there and wait because the new window has not been terminated. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Where does "start" come from? I've never seen something like it before. I thought it was something necessary for your ctetest to run, but it doesn't seem like it anymore. Also, what do you mean by "I am running this in a separate window"?

Comment: @Darthmouth So "start" basically starts a separate command prompt  [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx). So if you just open a cmd prompt and type in "start" it will start a new cmd. The only reason I want this is because I want the main code to be separate from the custom command, thus running it in a different (new) command prompt

Comment: Ah, windows, fun :P
Yeah, in that case I guess you're going to need the exit. But, I think you are only going to get the output from the "start" command with `subprocess.check_output`, not from the actual ctetest. I guess you are going to need to look into threading if you want to do two things at the same time, since subprocess will stop and wait until your new command prompts closes before continuing with the script. You could try chaining the command with &, like this: "start & ctetest .... & exit".

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot, do I still need to keep the commands in a list?

Comment: @Ted, yes, that's how subprocess needs it to be.

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know if I find a solution to this